# how can i limit the first two digit of an edittext to text to be 68 only?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/edit_text"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/roundededittext"
   android:digits="0123456789"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:hint="68 - #######"
   android:maxLength="9" />
```

how can I limit the first two digits of an android edittext to text to be 68 only?

Comment: I think you're trying to get phone number with mask. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask)

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it programmatically. Just place an un-editable textfield saying "68" in front of the edittext and add 68 in your program later.

Comment: In addition to Felix answer....You can also add textwatcher on edit text that observe input characters and change first two accordingly

Comment: i need to let the user start filling the editText with number starting 68, and don't allow to write anything otherwise

Answer (score 0):

try this on your activity

```
final EditText editext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    final String prefix = "68 - ";
    editext.setText(prefix);
    Selection.setSelection(editext.getText(), editext.getText().length());


    editext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(!s.toString().startsWith(prefix)){
                    editext.setText(prefix);
                    Selection.setSelection(editext.getText(), editext.getText().length());

                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `addTextChangedListener` for the textview and check in `onTextChanged` if the lengthAfter is less than 2 or whatever is the length of the prefix u wanted to set, and check if the text entered is 6 or 68..then set the text in `textView` as ""..else append the character sequence in text of `textview`